# An IOS UI Element for Long Text + Options

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am creating a survey application that involves having a series of long text and a selection of options at the end of each text.

Ideally, I'd like it to be a scrollable view where the user scrolls through the text, and at the bottom of the scroll, he will see a Picker for options, and a button to move to the next text (or automatically move to the next text after the user selects from the Picker).

I don't know if this is possible for iOS.

My other options would be a tab bar, with one button to display the text view, and the other, to display the options. I feel though that using a tab bar (or navigation bar) breaks the flow for the user with an additional tap to choose an answer.

Putting the scrollable text and the option on one fixed screen/view is not an option because the Picker already takes too much space, which is better used to present the lengthy text.

Any recommendations for the best UI element to use for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if have watched the WWDC 2010 videos than in session 123 they point out that the most frequently used option should be placed at the front of view hierarchy that means, you need to decide on what is important for user to see the text or the options in picker.

you can do something like this.

[image]

and for picker

[image]

or
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Robin. I personally find the Picker simply too big, when a combobox would do. It's nowhere near as pretty, but with limited space, the added real estate for other things is worth it.

Comment: there is no combo box in iphone. you need to get the work done with picker only.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you shouldn't put a picker at the bottom of a scrolling view like in [robin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567929/robin)'s screenshots (way to go making those tho). You should probably just have a set of UIButtons at the end of your scrolling content. If it's a variable set of buttons each time then you need to create them in code instead of interface builder.

You should add them as subviews of *something* and extend its bounds.. which *something* I'm not too sure of, the UITextView perhaps? Would it be best to have a parent UIView that contains the UITextView and the UIButtons? Somebody else needs to answer this.